# SFTP non-interactive mode transmission result

Tags: sftp

guys. I wrote a bash script for automatically transferring files with sftp. So, I used the non-interactive mode as below:

(echo "put /Django/EFFORT/Creep2Data-2/Test/CH0/new/end.txt"; echo quit)|sftp -b - username@localhost

It does work. But it doesn't show the statistics of transmission as an interactive mode. How can I get the statistics like below:
"Uploading LOGS/log.txt to /exports/home/username/log.txt   LOGS/log.txt   100%   1415     1.4KB/s   00:00"

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer that awkward invocation of `sftp` over `scp /Django/EFFORT/Creep2Data-2/Test/CH0/new/end.txt username@localhost:`?

Comment: apart from agreeing with twalberg: did yout try the `-v` switch?

Comment: @twalberg depending on the server configurations, it may accept sftp but not scp. This is the case when `scp` returns `This service allows sftp connections only.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature.  By default, if you are not running the command from an interactive terminal, the progress meter is turned off because it makes the output of the command very hard to parse.   If you want it, add `progress` before the put command.

```
(echo progress; echo "put /Django/EFFORT/Creep2Data-2/Test/CH0/new/end.txt"; echo quit)|sftp -b - username@localhost
```